# Error to launch and compile codeblocks code

Tags: c, linux, compilation, codeblocks, launch

I've just started to program in C and I tried to compile my first program with codeblocks, but when I do F9 to execute it, I got an error message which say *"Can't create output directory bin/Debug/"*.

I think it's because I'm not root user but I can't launch codeblocks in terminal, when I type "sudo codeblocks", I have an error message, *"Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?"*, so I'm stuck, don't know what to do. I'm in Ubuntu, latest version.

If anyone has an idea, he's welcome, thanks :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Show the full path of your project and source files. Everything should be in your home directory. It is not a good idea to run CodeBlocks as `root` to allow creating directories in places not owned by you. Another possible cause: Is there a file `bin/Debug`?

Comment: Thanks, I changed my path of the file when I created my project and it's working ! I don't know why but the default path leaded to a wrong directory :)

Comment: This site is not only meant to give you a personal answer but also a reference for people having similar problems, so adding the requested information to the question will make it more clear and allows to give a specific answer.